# Index range based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, conditional-statements

I have the pandas dataframe like below:

```
account   have  
  A         0     
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         0     
  A         1     
  A         1     
  B         0     
  B         0     
  B         0     
  B         0     
  B         0     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1     
  B         1
```

I want to result like this:

```
  account   have  
  A         12    
  A         12    
  A         0     
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         0     
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         3     
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12    
  B         12
```

I want to rank order after the specific value found and changed by `account` otherwise, it will return `12`. For example, the specific value is `2`, if any value that greater than or equal to `2` will be consider. In account `A`, it found `2` at index 2, the index will be change to `0` and any value after that less than `2` will be ranked order starting at `1`.

In account `B`, there is no value greater than or equal to `2`, the results return `12`.

In fact, I have like a million account, if there is any suggestion or point to start of, please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cumsum` to find your groups, and `cumcount` to fill them in.

---

```
m = df["have"].ge(2).groupby(df["account"]).cumsum()
df.groupby([df["account"], m]).cumcount().where(m.ne(0), 12)

0     12
1     12
2      0
3      1
4      2
5      0
6      1
7      2
8      3
9     12
10    12
11    12
12    12
13    12
14    12
15    12
16    12
17    12
dtype: int64
```